# Why can't the script do an if statement?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a game that allows you to get badges without having to work for them. But this is happening: Its giving me an error. That error is on the same line as a condition.
Here's the link to the file (please do not upload to roblox): https://www.mediafire.com/file/yyw8xui9yb4bft0/Place+for+badges.rbxl/file

I was expecting everything to go well because of the LocalScript. I don't know what's happening. I checked my code, and it seems flawless.
The problematic object is game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame.TextButton.Script

Now, I'll show the stuff:
In the text button, there are 3 relevant objects: A script, a localscript and a numbervalue.
The local script's code is:

```lua
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer.UserId
script.Parent.Value.Value = plr
```

Now, the script:

```lua
local player = script.Parent.Value.Value
local badgeservice = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local warning = false

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if not warning then
        warning = true
        if badgeservice:UserHasBadgeAsync(player, script.Parent.Parent.TextBox.Text) then
            badgeservice:AwardBadge(player, script.Parent.Parent.TextBox.Text)
        else
            script.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.Text = "You already have that badge!"
            wait(3)
            script.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.Text = "Enter badge ID and then press GIVE to get the badge with the corresponding ID"
        end
        warning = false
    end
end)
```

I keep getting an error: `Unable to cast string to int64`

Comment: Heyo, rather than sharing your entire place file with us, could you try to narrow it down to just the relevant code and share that as text here in the question?

Comment: you see the starter gui folder? in game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame.TextButton.Script, the if statement throws out an error on line 8. The error is User is invalid or does not exist, but around the time i did this question it was "Could not (Something i forgot) string to int64."

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that I'm not going to download your whole game to look at your code. Please edit your question to include the script and the specific error.

Comment: Here, I did it.

Comment: @Kylaaa Hey! I put the error and the code!

Comment: `UserHasBadgeAsync(int64 userId, int64 badgeId)` is expecting int64 as second argument, but is receiving `script.Parent.Parent.TextBox.Text` which contains a string not convertible to a number (an empty string?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goals correctly, you are trying to get game badges even for games you don't own. Unfortunately, this is not possible. According to the documentation for [BadgeService:AwardBadge](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BadgeService#AwardBadge) :

> AwardBadge grants a Player a badge given the player's UserId and the badge ID. In order to successfully award a badge, the following criteria must be met:
>
> - The player must be presently connected to the game.
> - The player must not already have the badge (note that a player may delete an awarded badge from their profile and be awarded the badge again).
> - The badge must be awarded from a server-side Script or a ModuleScript eventually required by a Script, not from a LocalScript.
> - The badge must be awarded in a place that is part of the game associated with the badge.
> - The owner of the place must also own the badge (for example, the owner must not have deleted the badge).
> - The badge must be enabled; check this using the IsEnabled property of the badge fetched through [BadgeService:GetBadgeInfoAsync()](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BadgeService#GetBadgeInfoAsync).

Since you are not the owner of the target badges, and this game is not associated with them, you cannot award them.